# Within a processwire setup how do you have a custom non-processwire-related PHP file load without 404 error? What .htaccess edits need to be made?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, processwire

I am working on a client website that runs on Processwire. I am trying to set up a regular ol'
PHP page *outside of **any** processwire stuff* that can just execute like a normal PHP page being served up.

Let's assume I am trying to set up "/foo/bar.php" at root where the page "bar.php" has this code:

**foo/bar.php**

```
<?php

    echo "Hello World";

?>
```

Presumably, if I visited **example.com/foo/bar.php** the server would see that that resource exists and serve up the content by showing the user "Hello World" in the browser. Instead, however, I get a 404 error that takes me to the PW 404 page.

Within the root's .htaccess file I see this:

```
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # 17. If the request is for a file or directory that physically exists on the server,
  # then don't give control to ProcessWire, and instead load the file
  # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(favicon\.ico|robots\.txt)
```

I must not understand this correctly since the actual bar.php file does physically exist... yet it won't work. If, however, I change the extension of ***bar.php*** to ***bar.txt*** the file *does load* at **example.com/foo/bar.txt** (displaying the PHP code shown above).

So, how can I adjust or update .htaccess to tell PW to ignore anything under /foo (including files and folders recursively) from being processed by PW?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything.  What is the complete rule in `.htaccess`? `RewriteCond` directives (ie. _conditions_) don't actually do anything by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything. As you suggest, those directives (although incomplete and not strictly correct) should already exclude requests for *any* physical file (and directory). What is more likely the issue is how PHP files are processed/handled on your server (CGI/reverse proxy?!) and the filesystem check is then failing for some reason.

As a workaround you could put a specific exception in for this subdirectory that is serving your PHP files. This could be implemented in a few ways... for example:

- Include another *condition* first on the list of conditions you posted:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/foo/
  ```

OR

- Include an exception at the top of the `.htaccess` file that prevents any further mod_rewrite directives being processed when this directory is requested (or rather, when a URL-path that starts `/foo/` is requested).

  ```
  RewriteRule ^foo(/|$) - [L]
  ```

OR

- Create another `.htaccess` in the subdirectory `/foo` that disables (or enables) the rewrite engine. mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default, so this completely overrides the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file.

  ```
  RewriteEngine Off
  ```